# one counter that works for all veriables

Tags: python, list, count, tuples, counter

```
def my_function(account_1,account_2,initiall_amount,log):
    final_list = [account_1_current_balance,account_2_current_balance]
    return final_list
account_1 = 'abc'
account_2 = 'xyz'
initiall_amount = 1000
log = [('abc','xyz',800), ('abc','xyz',100),('xyz','abc',500)]
```

in the following function i want to creat an e-cash system where i have the sender,reciver, and initall amount that represent the initill amount in both sender and reciver(assume that both have same amount) and the log show the transaction between reciver and sender.
here the log consist of trnsaction which have tuple the first element of tuple will be sender the second will be reciver and the third is amount that have to be send
now i want to print the current balance in final list
i can solve this by genrating each counter for reciver and sender but i do not want each counter for each reciver and sender because i may have hundreds of reciver and sender  i want only one counter that at the end print current balance in sender and reciver account
like in the above example the final list that will contain current balance will be
[600,1400] here the 600 shows the current amount of account1 , 1400 is of accoun2
becuae at bigning the amount in account1 was 1000 then he send 800 to acount2 so become 200 then he agin send 100 to acount2 so total become 100 after that he recive 500 from account2 so become 600
the same applies for account2
note : i want this this by one counter only

Comment: if there is a sender and receiver then there is a server, I would think that in such cases, these kinds of values are stored on server and changed there too, for a client to access that value they need to send a request. changing a value in multiple places is prone to errors, better to have that value in one place only and whatever needs that value asks for it, if it needs to be changed then a request can be sent to change it

Comment: thank you for your responce but here i just want to run this function i do not want to go ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure if this is what you want, but by making the account a dictionary it will be easier to add/subtract an amount.

```
initial_amount = 1000
account = dict()
account['abc'] = initial_amount
account['xyz'] = initial_amount
logs = [('abc','xyz',800), ('abc','xyz',100),('xyz','abc',500)]

for log in logs:
    #subtract from sender
    account[log[0]] -= log[2]

    #add to receiver
    account[log[1]] += log[2]


print(account['abc']) #prints out 600
print(account['xyz']) #prints out 1400
```

Comment: thank you so much i was looking for almost the same